# Extracting substring in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-mining, text-classification

I am working on a project that requires using machine learning to extract text from an article column, to categories possible areas the subjects might fall into

Input data frame:

[image]

The following rules are to be applied to produce the output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your work in this issue so far

Comment: Welcome to SO! I have deleted your last screenshot which was a duplicate of the third one. Please share your code that shows what you have tried to far to provide a [minimal reproducible exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://www.aboutdatablog.com/post/10-most-useful-string-functions-in-pandas

Comment: Hi Guys, many thanks for your correction. So far, I have used the .apply() function to create a new column that returns required values if certain words are gotten from any inout from the "article" column, however, this returns only a single value, and not multiple categories as shown in the expected output table.          'Category'] = df['Article'].apply(lambda x: '101' if 'yComputer Vision' in x else '102' if 'natural language processing' in x else '(none)')